# Why is my pomegranate tree dying?

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-health, plant-care, pomegranate

I planted a pomegranate seed in some soil and kept it indoors. I kept it alive for over a year, but recently it has dried, started to droop and the leaves are falling off.

It's in a ceramic pot of about 3-4 inch diameter without any holes in the bottom of it. What might cause it to be failing so badly and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pomegranates need full sun. There is also a chance that the roots are bound in that small container and over saturated with water due to the lack of drainage. This website recommended a 10 gallon pot. [More general info on growing Pomengrates](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/fruits/pomegranate/pomegranate-in-a-pot.htm)

Spring is a good time for transplanting. So you can try moving it to a bigger pot with better drainage and perhaps finding a basic fertilizer schedule. Depends on how dead it is.

Answer (score 0):

Several possible reasons at [wikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Grow-a-Pomegranate-Tree):

> **The leaves on my pomegranate are turning yellow. Why?**
>
> During the growing seasons of spring to early fall, this may be an indication of insufficient or too much watering. Like most plants, pomegranate trees need the right balance of moisture to grow well. Limit watering as the season changes from summer to fall, allowing the soil to dry out before watering again; after all, pomegranate is a desert plant and it's used to aridity. On the other hand, when the plant is first establishing itself in the ground after transplanting, it needs regular waterings to help the roots take hold. This might be another reason for yellowing of the leaves, so be sure to keep a transplanted tree well watered at least twice a week. Other reasons for yellowing leaves can include sap sucking insects, too much fertilizer or insufficient nitrogen and the cooling temperatures. In the latter case of falling temperatures, this is the normal cycle for the pomegranate, which is a deciduous tree and it will lose it leaves in late fall. If the plant appears otherwise healthy and it's late fall, assume that all is normal.

A bigger pot would seem called for and give you the opportunity to see if rootbound. I suspect not enough water.